# Finding xpath - I am misunderstanding something basic

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

my goal is to return "RPID16" in google sheets with:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://services.rsna.org/playbook/v1/playbook/complete/cpt/71250","something something")
```

I'm frustrated trying to understand the whole xpath concept. 
I thought it should be: 
/html/body/playbookterms/playbookterm[@radlexplaybookid]
or 
//playbookterm[@radlexplaybookid]

But /html/body/playbookterms/* or @* returns nothing.

I have only learned of xpath is today, but this should not be that hard.  I have been trying these queries here https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php without success.  Anything and everything past '//body' returns nothing.  I am missing something....

The XML code I am using below is copied from Chrome's developer tools.  But just in case, the original XML is returned from https://services.rsna.org/playbook/v1/playbook/complete/cpt/71250

```
<html><head></head><body><playbookterms xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd">
 <playbookterm radlexplaybookid="RPID16" shortname="CT Chest wo" longname="CT Chest wo IV Contrast" lettercode="CTCHU" automatedshortname="CT CHST WO IVCON" automatedlongname="CT CHEST WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" automatedlongdescription="A computed tomography  RADIOLOGY ORDERABLE imaging procedure focused on the CHEST WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" status="ACTIVE" statusreason="" statustext="" changetype="" changereasonpublic="" exportedtoloinc="TRUE" comment="">
  <componentradlexterms>
   <radlexterm id="190" attributename="CHEST" abbreviation="CHST" radlexid="RID1243" attributeid="2">
   <radlexterm id="247" attributename="WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" abbreviation="WO IVCON" radlexid="RID28768" attributeid="4">
   <radlexterm id="261" attributename="CT" abbreviation="CT" radlexid="RID10321" attributeid="7">
   <radlexterm id="637" attributename="RADIOLOGY ORDERABLE" abbreviation="RAD ORDER" radlexid="RID13060" attributeid="23">
  </radlexterm></radlexterm></radlexterm></radlexterm></componentradlexterms>
 </playbookterm>
</playbookterms>
</body></html>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: 
I have been playing with xlist at https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer. The tree viewer is extremely helpful for beginners.  However, if I load the XML from the link https://services.rsna.org/playbook/v1/playbook/complete/cpt/71250 directly, I get something different from what I get out of chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaybookTerms xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd">
 <PlaybookTerm radlexPlaybookId="RPID16" shortName="CT Chest wo" longName="CT Chest wo IV Contrast" letterCode="CTCHU" automatedShortName="CT CHST WO IVCON" automatedLongName="CT CHEST WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" automatedLongDescription="A computed tomography  RADIOLOGY ORDERABLE imaging procedure focused on the CHEST WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" status="ACTIVE" statusReason="" statusText="" changeType="" changeReasonPublic="" exportedToLoinc="TRUE" comment="">
  <ComponentRadlexTerms>
   <RadlexTerm id="190" attributeName="CHEST" abbreviation="CHST" radlexid="RID1243" attributeId="2"/>
   <RadlexTerm id="247" attributeName="WITHOUT IV CONTRAST" abbreviation="WO IVCON" radlexid="RID28768" attributeId="4"/>
   <RadlexTerm id="261" attributeName="CT" abbreviation="CT" radlexid="RID10321" attributeId="7"/>
   <RadlexTerm id="637" attributeName="RADIOLOGY ORDERABLE" abbreviation="RAD ORDER" radlexid="RID13060" attributeId="23"/>
  </ComponentRadlexTerms>
 </PlaybookTerm>
</PlaybookTerms>
```

From what I can see, the only difference is the later does not include the 'html' and 'body' layers. So it would seem obvious that

```
/html/body/*[local-name()='playbookterms']/*[local-name()='playbookterm']/@radlexplaybookid
```

should become

```
/*[local-name()='playbookterms']/*[local-name()='playbookterm']/@radlexplaybookid
```

Yet again, nothing I try seems to yield anything other than "No Match!"

Ok:

```
//*[local-name()='PlaybookTerm']/@radlexPlaybookId
```

yields the same things as the original XML did with

```
/html/body/*[local-name()='playbookterms']/*[local-name()='playbookterm']/@radlexplaybookid
```

According to https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester, both yield:

```
radlexPlaybookId="RPID16"
```

Most importantly

```
=IMPORTXML("https://services.rsna.org/playbook/v1/playbook/complete/cpt/71250","//*[local-name()='PlaybookTerm']/@radlexPlaybookId")
```

returns "Error Imported Xml content can not be parsed."

The new xpath works on the new XML:
http://xpather.com/
https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

But here: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php it gives the error Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => DOMDocument::loadXML(): Unsupported version '1.1' in Entity, line: 1
    [file] => /var/www/html/online-toolz.com/functions/XPATH.php
    [line] => 11
)
Error:DOMDocument::loadXML(): Unsupported version '1.1' in Entity, line: 1

Maybe this is a version limitation in google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

With your element

```
<playbookterms xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd">
```

you were defining a default namespace on the `<playbookterms>` element and all of its children. So you have to set this namespace before selecting the elements you want.

For example, if you set a namespace-prefix `shm` to your namespace with

```
xmlns:shm="http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd"
```

you could access the desired value `RPID16` with the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
/html/body/shm:playbookterms/shm:playbookterm/@radlexplaybookid
```

But if you cannot define the namespace in your `=IMPORTXML` function, you can override the namespaces of the elements with the following general expression:

```
/html/body/*[local-name()='playbookterms']/*[local-name()='playbookterm']/@radlexplaybookid
```

The result is

> RPID16

Comment: Thank you! Namespace is this missing piece I think.  The tutorials I am reading  do not yet get into namespace, so I think that points me in the right general direction.  However the XML I copied from my browser I think is incomplete.  I tried the tools at https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester and https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer (very helpful). However the website retrieved XML has a small - but critical - difference.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer provided you some help on your way to understand XPath.

Comment: If you like to give me a 'thanks', you can accept the answer by clicking on the hook next to it on the left side.